# SQL query with top x records and full record count

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

I have a complex sql query, that returns top 100 records, which is used to build a grid with pagination.
For rendering the pagination I require total record count. Right now I am querying the database two times, first to get the total record that would yield for specified where condition (say it would return 12,567)

```
Select count(*) as TotalRecords from (select a.field1, b.field2, c.field3 from abc a inner join xyz b on b.id = a.id inner join .... where ...) temp
```

and second time to get the top 100 records

```
select TOP 100 a.field1, b.field2, c.field3 from abc a inner join xyz b on b.id = a.id inner join .... where ...
```

The problem with this approach is performance impact due to heavy weight query, sometimes its taking long time to run both queries.

Is there any way to get top 100 records along with total record count without querying two times?

Comment: How would you integrate the total record count in the single result set - an extra column? I dont think you would see a significant performance gain - it is not the fact that you query twice that takes time.

Comment: You can use SELECT **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS** TOP 100 a.field1, b.field2, c.field3 from abc a inner join xyz b on b.id = a.id inner join .... where ...

Comment: Your tags specify Oracle, MySQ and SQL-Server. Which is it?

Comment: With Oracle and SQL Server a window function using `count(*) over ()` might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It would not be possible to get this done in single time, as both of your query returns different result set. One returns only the record count while other returns top 100 records. Count of records wont much impact query performance but you can also use Count(fieldName) to optimize your query.